# nvidia-smi - No devices were found - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: nvidia, permissions, cuda, gpu

1. Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
2. Have 1 Nvidia GPU
3. Installed Nvidia drivers and CUDA 11.2
4. UserA has "sudo" capability i.e. in group "sudo"
5. UserB is a normal user
6. UserC is in group "cuda_allow"
7. At terminal, I could run "nvidia-smi" properly for UserA, UserB and UserC.
8. File permission for /dev/nvidia0 is 666
9. At /dev/nvidia0, I changed the permission to 660 => sudo chmod 660 /dev/nvidia0
10. At /dev/nvidia0, I replaced "root" group to "cuda_allow" group => sudo chown :cuda_allow /dev/nvidia0
11. At terminal for UserA, run 'nvidia-smi' and an error is encountered. The error => No devices were found
12. At terminal for UserB, run 'nvidia-smi' and same error is encountered => No devices    were found.
13. At terminal for UserC, run 'nvidia-smi' and it run properly i.e. A table of information was displayed.
14. Add UserA to group "cuda_allow" => sudo usermod -aG cuda_allow usera
15. Check to ensure kst is in group "cuda_allow" i.e. members cuda_allow => Confirmed userA is in group "cuda_allow"
16. Rerun "nvidia-smi" and error => No devices were found

Question
Added "UserA" which has "sudo" capability to group "cuda_allow" is not behaving the same as "UserC".  "UserC" is in group "cuda_allow" and does not have "sudo" capability. Question is why by adding "UserA" to group "cuda_allow", I can't run 'nvidia-smi'?

I found out that at terminal for "UserA", I run "sudo nvidia-smi" successfully.  Is it possible to run it without having the "sudo" in front of "nvidia-smi"?